# how to change spinner in TableLayout

Tags: android, spinner, tablelayout

I created a Table Layout, which contains Table Rows.
Every Table Row contains some Linnear Layour. Linear Layout has a child Spinner. When I create a Table Layout firstly I am writing each TableRow in  `ArrayList<TableRow> list_rows`.
I set different values for some spinners. When I update activity with Table Layout, my function of redrawing Table Layout is called, it works correctly. 
My problem is after updating an activity i want to change value of some spinners and the next update of Table Layout should show table with new spinners, but it doesn't happen.

```
 public void addColumnInRows(TableRow tableRow, boolean name, boolean has_data, int number_of_student, int number_of_column)  
    {
            // some code
            spinner = new Spinner(getContext());
            final String[] mark_5 = {"", "a", "i", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}; // elemets in spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mark_5);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
            spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            spinner.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    parent.setSelection(position);
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });

            if (has_data == true) // draw TableLayout if i have a data
            {
                journal.Statistics(DrawTable.this, stat);
                journal.Statistics(DrawTable.this, journal.stat);
                for (int position = 0; position < mark_5.length; position++) {
                    if (number_of_column - 1 < stat.get(number_of_student).size()) {
                        if (stat.get(number_of_student).get(number_of_column-1).equals(mark_5[position])) {
                            spinner.setSelection(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
     }
```

Comment: you always put the same elements in your adapter. you want to change the values or the selection in your spinners?